# Installing Keras package with conda install

Tags: python, anaconda, python-import, keras

I have installed `Anaconda` package on a server as a user account, then I installed `keras` by `conda install keras`,but after installation, when I run `import keras`, it raised `no module names keras`,anyone can help? thanks very much!

Comment: Works for me. What OS are you on? What Python version? Do you use a conda environment?

Comment: I'm running on remote server using SSH, the server is UNIX, previously there is already python 2.7 installed on the server, what do you mean use a conda environment?

Comment: Likely that you use a different  Python than in which you installed the library. Try `which -a python` to see what you got.

Comment: the outcome of `which -a python` is `/bin/python`, my anaconda is installed in `/projdata3/info_fil/wangtao/conda`

Comment: What if you try: `conda install -c conda-forge keras`

Answer (score 6):

One solution could be creating a conda environment:

```
conda create -n keras python=3.5
```

Now activate it:

```
conda activate keras
```

and install keras:

```
(keras)$ conda install keras
```

Try if it works:

```
(keras)$ python
>>> import keras
```

Comment: then I tried `which activate`, it gives `/projdata3/info_fil/wangtao/conda/bin/activate`, then I cd to `/projdata3/info_fil/wangtao/conda/bin` and run `source activate keras` again, this time it raised `BASH_VERSION: Undefined variable`

Comment: Are using a shell that is not `bash`? Change to `bash`

Answer (score 0):

Once creating the Conda environment, use the command below to list available environment:

```
conda info -e
```

Once activate your conda environment, you can try to install Keras by

```
pip install keras==version_your_desired.
```

Then use

```
pip freeze
```

to check the version.