# How to install Keras in Python 3.6?

Tags: keras, python-3.6

I'm having trouble installing the Keras library for Python 3.6. Whenever I try to install Keras, it is throwing an error and when I searched on the internet, Keras had been released for up to Python 3.5. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Please show the error you are getting. Without it it's unlikely anyone will be able to help you. Your OS may also be relevant.

Answer (score 5):

Follow this method if you have Anaconda and Python version 3.6.

First, create a new conda environment,

```
conda create -n keras python=3.5
```

Now activate it,

```
source activate keras
```

and install Keras,

```
conda install keras
```

Test if it works,

```
    $ python 
>>>import keras
```

You will get the following message if it was successful:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
```

[Click here to see Mike Müller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41415759/5706413)

Answer (score 2):

I used `sudo pip install keras` to download.

I have both python 2.7 and 3.6 installed on my Mac. I used `pip -V` to check my python version of installation. Probably you used invalid version of python to download.

Screenshot of the install being done on my computer: 
[image: Mac intallation screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps , Tensorflow dosnt support py3.7 as of now , so 3.6 is better , 
 I recommend using environment , (venv , conda(preferred) ),

For conda

```
conda create -n keras python=3.6
source activate keras
conda install tensorflow keras
#for faster installation
pip install keras
```

For virtualenv

```
virtualenv -p python3 keras
source keras/bin/activate
pip install keras tensorflow numpy
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following at a command prompt:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
pip install --upgrade keras
```

Also, refer the following link for more detail:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip