# How to install keras python 3.6?

Tags: python, keras

[image]

Do you know how to solve the error "No module named "setuptools.build_meta"? If I try to install the "setup..." it says "couldn't find a version that satisfies..."

Comment: can you provide a list of the actions you took from start and the full output of the error?

Comment: Like @humle_coder said, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44310326/how-to-install-keras-in-python-3-6.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'setuptools.build\_meta'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61159636/importerror-no-module-named-setuptools-build-meta)

Comment: I add the picture with problem.Then there are a lot of red lines with the error in the end. I use 32-bit system Windows.

Comment: I checked those links but I don't have anaconda. Maybe is there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by upgrading setup tools. But here is another problem with h5py.

[image]

Comment: Please ask another question if you have additional problems instead of putting it in an answer.